# ggplot classic theme missing axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes, missing-features

I have a curious problem with ggplot: the axes are missing. Here is sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
z <- data.frame(x = seq(1,10,1), y = seq(1,10,1))
d <- ggplot(z, aes(x = x, y = y))
d <- d + geom_line()
d <- d + theme_classic()
ggsave("test.eps", device=cairo_ps, width=15, height=8, units="cm", dpi=300)
```

Version information:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "i486-slackware-linux-gnu"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"

> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] '2.1.0'
```

I have attached the offending image :)

[image]

Comment: if you feel like living on the bleeding edge, you can do `devtools::install_github("Katiedaisey/ggplot2")` -- or wait for the pull request to bring the fix into `hadley/ggplot2` or wait for a bug-fix release ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, problem solved now. Bill